# How to execute an image of mariadb?

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

A few days ago I saw myself on the stage of having to install mariadb on my pc that already has mysql, I managed to have both instances thanks to docker. I followed this [publication](https://www.codementor.io/arpitbhayani/setup-multiple-mysql-servers-with-different-versions-docker-du107solq) and managed to install docker and an image.

```
docker run --name mariadb-10.2.10-container -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword -p 127.0.0.1:3311:3306 -d mariadb:10.2.10
```

The pc did not turn off until suddenly it gave an error today and it was necessary to restart it.

Because I do not have any previous experience with docker now that I try to start the container I do not achieve it.

I share my attempts

`docker images` return this

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mysql               5.5                 0da48351c371        4 weeks ago         205MB
mariadb             10.2.10             abcee1d29aac        4 months ago        396MB
```

When I try

`docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword -p 127.0.0.1:3311:3306 -d mariadb:10.2.10`

After this I hope to connect to Mariadb through Port 3311 so I worked on my application before the incident. Now the container is running but he seems not to be listening at port 3311, because I am not able to connect from the application or from the MySQL client.

`docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
48041cc27494        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        127.0.0.1:3311->3306/tcp   heuristic_shaw
```

Now I managed to connect and I see that the problem is that the database does not exist

I have lost my database ?, If so, will there be a way to recover it? I've done something wrong?

By SO user suggestion I show the result of executing the command `docker ps -a | grep mariadb`

```
48041cc27494        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour               127.0.0.1:3311->3306/tcp   heuristic_shaw
3af4187383a9        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (1) About an hour ago                              amazing_stonebraker
f1873e7b117c        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (1) About an hour ago                              confident_mayer
7d1d1fc27cf0        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                              admiring_mendeleev
0a828a6ad5f4        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (1) About an hour ago                              tender_yonath
4802f926ef5d        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                                    wizardly_mcnulty
673898d10840        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                                    elated_banach
d444e40e5ccc        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                                    elated_cori
49fa7950e262        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                                    gifted_engelbart
987d5e8c80db        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                                    festive_boyd
6b30e16a91bf        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                                    wizardly_edison
3aea221c1477        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                                    inspiring_mcnulty
5e95beb0b4d4        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                                    sad_hoover
21f9df586582        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                                    goofy_archimedes
93b6c5db2178        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                                    sad_fermi
0fba8554b87f        mariadb:10.2.10     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 days ago          Exited (255) 2 hours ago       127.0.0.1:3311->3306/tcp   mariadb-10.2.10-container
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you run this command (to check if the older container still exists) and show us the output? `docker ps -a | grep mariadb`

Comment: Thanks for answering, It is a very extensive result I put it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker run` creates a new container each time.

So, when your trying to resume the older container with running this,
`docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword -p 127.0.0.1:3311:3306 -d mariadb:10.2.10`

It is actually creating a new container.

So, the work around for you is:

1. Make sure, the previous container exists with name `mariadb-10.2.10-container` (as you named your container to this in the 1st command).

If you see the last line of the output of `docker ps -a | grep mariadb`, that's the ancient container we are looking for!

2. Now, we have to restart it. But before that we need to stop container `48041cc27494`, because it is listening on `127.0.0.1:3311`. Run, `docker stop 48041cc27494`. It should be stopped successfully.
3. Now start the `ancient` container! you can run either `docker start 0fba8554b87f` or `docker start $(docker ps -a -q -f name=mariadb-10.2.10-container)`. Any of these two command should resume your container. You old data should be there. Now you can connect to it just like before.

Further, You should add a `restart` policy for this container, so that you won't need to restart every time it stops.

- Read about how to [start containers automatically](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)
- As your container have already been created, you should update it with `docker container update` command. See doc [docker container update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_update/).